# Remove &nbsp; between p tags

Tags: javascript, regex

Using regex in JavaScript, how would I replace the following tags with an empty string?

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
.
..
...
```

There could be any number of `&nbsp;` entities between the p tags.

Comment: can there be anything **but** `&nbsp;` inside those `p` tags?

Comment: if there is something else between the p tags, then dont remove this whitespace

Comment: Can your `<p>` tags have attributes?

Comment: If you don't mind me saying, before you even try to solve this problem you should be asking yourself 1) why are you using `&nbsp;` for spacing?  CSS would be more flexible, reliable and semantic.  And 2) why are the extra `&nbsp;` tags being generated in the first place?  It would be easier to remove them at that point than to have to go back in and post-process the output.

Comment: no attributes. these are being generated by tinymce when the rich text editor has nothing but whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code. you need:

```
var x = '<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>';
x.replace(/<p>(&nbsp;)+<\/p>/i, '');
```

Comment: A little nitpciking, but you should change that capturing group to a non-capturing group as the result is not being used. Like this: `/<p>(?:&nbsp;)+<\/p>/i`

Comment: Hi @BaBL86 how to fix if <p>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p> having space in between

Answer (score 2):

"your content filled with &nbsp".replace(/(&nbsp;)/gi, '');

Comment: add `g` flag to the regex

Comment: The `*` isn't needed, not at the `(` and `)`. `"your content filled with &nbsp;".replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');`

Comment: you don't resolve topic problem but broke good strings with &nbsp;